# Duplicate, copy the values from the first row (model table) for N number of rows?

Tags: python, django, dataframe, django-models, django-queryset

I have a Django model table.

In which the content is only one - the first row of the table.

But I need to duplicate - this first single row.

I need to fill 20 (for example, N number of rows of the model table) with the same values as from the first row of the model table.

How can you duplicate, copy the values from the first row (model table) for N number of rows?

--

```
before

0   2023-01-02 10:00:00         60.37         50.37          13.651          12.189

after

0   2023-01-02 10:00:00         60.37         50.37          13.651          12.189
1   2023-01-02 10:00:00         60.37         50.37          13.651          12.189
2   2023-01-02 10:00:00         60.37         50.37          13.651          12.189
3   2023-01-02 10:00:00         60.37         50.37          13.651          12.189
4   2023-01-02 10:00:00         60.37         50.37          13.651          12.189
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query your model ordering by `id`, call `.values()` to return a dictionary and select the first element. Then, remove the `id` key from this dictionary and use the rest of the data to create more objects:

```
data = MyModel.objects.all().order_by('id').values()[0]
data.pop('id')
for i in range(20):
    MyModel.objects.create(**data)
```

or if you know the `id` value then you can use `.filter(id=id)` instead of `.all() while also removing the ordering.`:

```
data = MyModel.objects.filter(id=1).values()[0]
...
```